# Galloway effect in Batley and Spen

Tags: united-kingdom, election

This TLDR News [video](https://youtu.be/g0mSrW0hScQ&t=482) implies that George Galloway's 8000 votes in the 2021 Batley and Spen by-election come from the Conservative party voters in previous elections. A stance also held by the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Batley_and_Spen_by-election) article, though that article also mentions explicit appeals to Labour voters.

> George Galloway's socially conservative stance may have attracted some Tory-leaning voters.<sup>[[7]](https://inews.co.uk/news/politics/george-galloway-batley-and-spen-by-election-results-votes-candidates-1083223)</sup> Galloway stated he was aiming to win over Labour voters in order to oust Keir Starmer as Labour leader.

Additionally there seemed to be a strong focus from Galloway on Muslim issues and the UK Muslim community [votes](https://www.mend.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Power-of-the-Muslim-vote-and-Muslim-voting-patterns.pdf) 64% Labour, 25% Conservatives based on the data I've seen.

Is there any available data specific to Batley and Spen that shows which parties George Galloway's voters previously supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one opinion poll conducted by [Survation](https://www.survation.com/conservatives-lead-new-polling-for-batley-and-spen-by-election/) from 9 to 17 June.

In the crosstab with the 2019 General Election Vote, 80% of those who said they would vote for Mr. Galloway said they voted Labour in 2019, with none having said they previously voted Conservative.

Note that only 20 people in the poll said they would vote for Mr. Galloway, and so a large margin of error applies.  Also, only 6% of respondents said they would vote for Mr. Galloway, well short of the 22% he received in the by-election.

Comment: I began writing an answer based on the [election history](https://members.parliament.uk/constituency/3309/election-history) but realised it wasn't enough on its own. It does, however, support a few points in your answer. There was a much higher voter turnout for the 2021 by-election than the 2016 one and the labour win was vastly reduced compared to previous years